# working with mysql and php

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to add a column in teacher table the name of the column is given by text field the code is here

```
$name=  cleanString($_POST['prog']);
$query_1="alter table teacher add '$name' varchar(40) null";
if (!mysql_query($query_1, $link)){
    echo mysql_error();
}
```

but it gives the error like
"You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ''students' varchar(40) null' at line 1"

but when I use the query
    $query_1="alter table program_course add 'students' varchar(40) null";

this query works fine and there is no error any body who can help me about it please

Comment: **Danger**: You are using [an **obsolete** database API](http://stackoverflow.com/q/12859942/19068) and should use a [modern replacement](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqlinfo.api.choosing.php).  You are also likely to be **vulnerable to [SQL injection attacks](http://bobby-tables.com/)** (a function called `cleanString` sounds generic enough that it is likely to have problems)) that a modern API would make it easier to [defend](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/best-way-to-prevent-sql-injection-in-php) yourself from.

Comment: Don't add courses in the teacher table. Create a course table and give it a teach column.

Comment: You sure that query runs fine exactly as it does? I didn't think the column would add with it being a string? Try removing the single quotes around the var?

Comment: may be you are not connected with mysql(principal)

Comment: dear this is not the problem I have used the same function for my other quries also but the problem is only with this query if a hard code the name of the column then there is no problem when i put the variable name in the query then it gives the error

Comment: I am connected with mysql it is sure and I have tried by removing single quotes around the var but it gives error it only does not gives error when i use hard coded name for column

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
$query_1="alter table teacher add `$name` varchar(40) null";
```

Instead of :

```
$query_1="alter table teacher add '$name' varchar(40) null";
```

You were using invalid characters. You need ` instead of '

Comment: Don't you need {} around the variable? `{$name}`

Comment: @Hammerstein it is optional